# Creating a note with checkbox list in Evernote uisng html in Zapier Api

Tags: html, api, zapier, evernote

I am using Zapier api to create a note in Evernote. Zapier allows for creating a note using html. I can get a note to be created but can't seem to get a note with a checkbox list created. Perhaps I am doing something wrong with the html code. Does anyone know how to create a checkbox list in Evernote using the html code in Zapier?

I have tried the following html code in Zapier when trying to create the note but this code doesn't work:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked> I have a boat<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked> I have a boat<br>
```

Only creates text results and note checkbox list

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3):

Per the [evernote docs](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php), it looks like you need to use the `<en-todo>` tag, specific to evernote:

> en-todo marks the location of a "To Do" checkbox within a note's content. en-todo does not encompass any specific text; it is a self-closing tag that can include a single attribute:

```html
<en-todo/>An item that I haven't completed yet.   
<br/>  
<en-todo checked="true"/>An completed item.
```

Comment: Thank you so much xavdid!!!! Very much appreciated. I couldn't figure this out. Very happy you've helped me :-D

Comment: No problem! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: This helped me too, @JeremyPyle you should mark this as the correct answer